# How to delete all instance names in a list?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

```
mylist = ['dogs', 'cats', 'cats']
```

If I type `mylist.remove('cats')`, it deletes only one cats in my list, but I want to delete all cats in my list without loops, because loops are going to crash the way I want to.

EDIT: it's a little trick to explain, for example, it's going to crash because I'm trying to develop a module to remove equal elements from a list. mylist[i] returns dogs firstly, I delete it, but after another loop, mylist[i] doesn't return dogs anymore, but cats. That's why I want to delete all instances in a single statement regardless of the index loop.

Comment: What does "loops are going to crash the way I want to" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new list with a list comprehension to avoid an explicit loop:

```
mylist = [item for item in mylist if item != 'cats']
```

Comment: Note that you can do `mylist[:] = ...` if you want to modify the list in-place, at a minor cost to efficiency (an extra copy).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method for removing all elements from a list. You have to use a loop. What is wrong with:

```
In [129]: x=['dog','cat','cat']
In [136]: [elt for elt in x if elt!='cat']
Out[136]: ['dog']
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the supplied list copy must be modified inplace, I would suggest filter.

```
>>> x = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x != 'foo', ['foo', 'foo', 'bar'])
>>> x
<itertools.ifilter object at 0xb70ba2ec>
>>> list(x)
['bar']
```

Comment: List comprehensions (or generator expressions) are clearer and more idiomatic in Python.