# How can i put number in the list in python

Tags: python

I have numbers like this :

```
-1
1
2
3
-1
1
3
2
```

and i would like to put this number in list like `[-1,1,2,3,-1,1,3,2]` and delete `-1` from the list.

Comment: Where do you get these numbers from? Keyboard input, a file, ...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Why are you putting -1 if you are going to delete it?

Comment: The question lacks some "context". Please be more specific about what you want. Is that a generic routine you want to write ? Do you need to remove only "-1" occurences from any given list ?

Comment: I am get this numbers form this code:                              x = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
y = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
for i in x:
  for j in y:
    x, elist = gt.shortest_path(g, g.vertex(i), g.vertex(j))
    xx = [str(v) for v in x]
    print xx
    print len(xx)-1 . So the number in the form of a column, and i want her in the form of a list without -1.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> a = [-1, 1, 2, 3, -1, 1, 3, 2]
>>> a = [x for x in a if x != -1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put the numbers in list instead of Column?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: l = [-1,1,2,3,-1,1,3,2]

In [6]: l = [item for item in l if item != -1]

In [7]: l
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put the numbers in list instead of Column?

Answer (score 1):

here is the code:

```
In [1]: [int(x) for x in "-1 1 2 3 -1 1 3 2".split() if x!="-1"]
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: This code would have worked fine before the poster changed the format of the input numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put the numbers in list instead of Column?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small improvement on agf's answer. You don't need to fiddle with indexing to remove newline characters. Rather use the strip method (it will also work for all kinds of line terminations, not just the Unix '\n'):

```
intlist = [int(x.strip()) for x in open(filename) if x.strip() != '-1']
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put the numbers in list instead of Column?