# Python: Creating a filter function

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to create a function:

```
filter(delete,lst)
```

When someone inputs:

```
filter(1,[1,2,1])
```

returns `[2]`

What I have come up with was to use the list.remove function but it only deletes the first instance of delete.

```
def filter(delete, lst):

"""

Removes the value or string of delete from the list lst

"""

   list(lst)

   lst.remove(delete)

   print lst
```

My result:

```
filter(1,[1,2,1])
```

returns `[2,1]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list

Comment: I'd suggest choosing a different name for your function. There is a built-in `filter` function and you'll be masking it.

Comment: the reason i called my function "filter" was at the request of the instructor in this assignment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with list comprehensions:

```
def filt(delete, lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x != delete]
```

Or alternatively, with the built-in filter function:

```
def filt(delete, lst):
    return filter(lambda x: x != delete, lst)
```

And it's better *not* to use the name `filter` for your function, since that's the same name as the built-in function used above

Comment: +1. I'd only add that it's good not to use `filter` as a name, since it's already a built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
And the reason I called my function "filter" was at the request of my instructor in this assignment.

Comment: HighAllegiant : In those cases, **please** add the Homework tag to your question. Giving the answer to you in absolutely unhelpful.

Comment: Between this and your other question, it looks to me like your instructor is hell-bent on making people do easy problems the hard way for no reason. :(

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from Óscar López but you should also learn to use the existing Python *[filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)* function:

```
>>> def myfilter(tgt, seq):
        return filter(lambda x: x!=tgt, seq)

>>> myfilter(1, [1,2,1])
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Custom Filter Function

```
def my_filter(func,sequence):
    res=[]
    for variable in sequence :
        if func(variable):
            res.append(variable)
    return res

def is_even(item):
    if item%2==0 :
        return True
    else :
        return False
 
    

seq=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(my_filter(is_even,seq))
```

Comment: Output will be [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].Here the address of is_even and func is same.

Answer (score 0):

Custom filter function in python:

```
def myfilter(fun, data):
    return [i for i in data if fun(i)]
```