# Remove elements from list

Tags: python, filter, list-comprehension

I have a variable:

```
x = 4
```

And I have a list:

```
list = [{'name': u'A', 'value': '1'}, {'name': u'B', 'value': '4'}, {'name': u'C', 'value': '2'}]
```

How can I exclude/remove the element in list where value=x?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: this isn't an exact duplicate, because it is a property of the value, not the value itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is perfect for this.

```
[ k for k in list if int(k['value']) != x ]
```

You can also use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter), but I believe list comprehensions are preferred in terms of style:

```
filter(lambda p: int(p['value']) != x, list)
```

edit: noticed your values are strings, so I added an int conversion.

Comment: [List comprehensions are indeed preferred over `map()` and  `filter()` (and don't even think about `reduce()`!)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) The BDFL says so!