# How do I remove hyphens from a nested list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In the nested list:

```
x = [['0', '-', '3', '2'], ['-', '0', '-', '1', '3']]
```

how do I remove the hyphens?

```
x = x.replace("-", "")
```

gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`, and

```
print x.remove("-")
```

gives me `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Comment: Python is actually documented: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable

Comment: edited to better explain my difficulty :P

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a list of lists. `replace()` will substitute a pattern string for another within a *string*. What you want is to remove an item from a list. `remove()` will remove the first occurrence of an item. A simple approach:

```
for l in x:
    while ("-" in l):
        l.remove("-")
```

For more advanced solutions, see the following: [Remove all occurrences of a value from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: You truly are the king of kings!  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm inclined to agree with @jogojapan, though- Python's documentation is quite extensive, and this is a simple question. Try to do some research next time.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that too.  I should have included that error as well.