# Why are the underscores not all being removed from the list? Python

Tags: python, list, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

For a list:

```
char = ['a', '_', '_', 'b' ]
```

How does one remove all instances of '_' from the list, so it ends up looking like:

```
char = ['a', 'b' ]
```

I've tried:

```
char.remove('_')
```

which gives me:

```
char = ['a', '_', 'b']
```

Why is this, and how can I get it to remove all underscores in the list?

Answer (score 6):

`list.remove` only removes the first instance of a match - you can use a list-comprehension:

```
char = [el for el in char if el != '_']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options considered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list) post that is a close duplicate perhaps of this one. One of them is :

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,2,2,2,3,4]  
>>> filter (lambda a: a != 2, x)  
[1, 3, 3, 4]
```