# Python - "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error

Tags: python, list, function

My instructions in a codecademy project are to

> Define a function called purify that takes in a list of numbers, removes all odd numbers in the list, and returns the result. For example, purify([1,2,3]) should return [2]. Do not directly modify the list you are given as input; instead, return a new list with only the even numbers.

The code I have come up with is:

```
def purify(numbers):

pure = numbers

for num in pure:
    if num % 2 != 0:
        pure = pure.remove(num)

return pure
```

And the error is:

> Oops, try again. Your function crashed on [1] as input because your function throws a "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error.

As I've come to understand it, this means something in my code is being returned as "None". Or there is no data there. I can't seem to find what's wrong with this short and simple code, unless it's in my if statement. Thanks in advance.

So I made the edit within the code to remove "pure = pure.remove(num)" and that solved the none issue. However, when running the code it still fails the input of [4,5,5,4] and returns [4,5,4].

New Code:

```
def purify(numbers):

    pure = numbers

    for num in pure:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            pure.remove(num)

    return pure
```

Comment: Your code makes exactly the same mistake [the same classmate I linked to earlier did](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25326339/3001761) (maybe you should have read it?); **don't modify lists while iterating over them**. Also, `list.remove` is in-place, so will `return None`. Also, `pure = numbers` **does not** create a copy, so you aren't meeting the specification.

Comment: Make sure to post *valid* code that *accurately* reproduces the problem. Trivially, the indenting is incorrect and the presented code will not parse.

Comment: list.remove return None. It modifies the list instead. Also, do not modify the list while you are iterating over it

Comment: So if pure = numbers does not make a copy, and I can't modify a list while iterating over it, what are my options to not edit the original list and return a clean list?

Comment: For the love of everything, *read the question* I keep providing a link to! There are several answers there that aren't unique to strings and vowels, and will work happily with lists of even and odd numbers. To copy a list, do e.g. `pure = numbers[:]`. Consider adding to an empty list instead of removing from a full one. Use `filter` or a list comprehension.

Comment: Removing the "pure =" solved the None issue but still did not return properly. Using the filter/list comprehension as explained in the marked answer was what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first problem is that you change the list while iterating over it. [**DO NOT** change lists while you are iterating over them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527966/why-does-python-not-act-intuitively-when-someone-attempts-to-change-a-list-while) You will miss out on some of the values in the loop.

The second problem is that `list.remove` acts in-place and returns None. Thus, when you do `pure = pure.remove(num)`, you set `pure` to `None`, which is no longer iterable, which in turn is what causes the error. Instead, you can filter the list as follows

```
def purify(numbers):
    return [num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: This is great. This is what I was looking for. Is this the filter function or list comprehension? I still don't grasp list comprehension which is why I ask. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a list comprehension. It adds each item `num` from `numbers` to the new list (`num for num in numbers`), but only iff ([that's a word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff)) `num` is even (`if num % 2 == 0`).

Answer (score 2):

Well that error means that python is trying to iterate over a `None` object.

The only iteration in your code is your `for` loop, so `pure` must be the `None`.

Also, don't forget to indent properly:

```
def purify(numbers):

    pure = numbers

    for num in pure:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            pure = pure.remove(num)

    return pure
```

So pure is either being defined as `None` when you set it equal to `numbers` or it's being defined when you assign it from `pure.remove(num)`.  When you look up the documentation for remove(num), you see that it operates **in-place**, so it doesn't return anything useful (`None` usually).  What you want to do it remove the `pure =` part in the `for` loop.  You might notice that you end up skipping elements in your loop, but that would a separate problem with this piece of code (modifying something you're iterating over).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `pure`'s type is but it seems that it's a mutable object. `pure.remove` updates `pure` in place, and therefore returns `None`. You shouldn't set it into `pure`. Moreover, you shouldn't modify objects you iterate over during the iteration itself.

**EDIT:** The previous code snippet I put here was incorrect, as mentioned in the comments. I suggest you pick one of the methods mentioned in the other answers. If you're really interested in maintaining the general structure of your current solution, here is a workaround that uses the [copy](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module:

```
import copy

def purify(numbers):
    pure = copy.copy(numbers) # a shallow copy
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            pure.remove(num)

    return pure
```

Note that `numbers`'s class should implement the `__copy__` method for this to work. You've mentioned in your comments above that `numbers` is a `list`, so the built-in implementation works for you. However, for a `list` you can simply do the following:

```
pure = numbers[:]
```

Comment: You can also copy using `pure = numbers[:]` instead of using `copy`

Comment: Yeah, I just now noticed that `numbers` is a `list`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
def purify(numbers):
    sequence = []     //starting with a an empty 
    for f in sequence:
        if f%2 -1:    //filtering out odd numbers,alternative to f%2 ==0
            sequence.append(f) //append each even number to the empty list
    return sequence
```

N/B:starting with an empty list ensures list is not modified