# How to remove all 0 from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'1': 2, '0': 0, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 0, '6': 0, '9': 0, '8': 0}
```

I want to remove all items with a value of zero

So that it comes out like this

```
{'1': 2, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1}
```

Comment: Write some code. Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242 And why are you using a dict instead of a list?

Comment: Close cousin, if not exact duplicate: [Remove all occurences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: @MattBall I'm learning dictionaries not lists

Comment: Well I been trying to do this for like an hour now. So I decided to seek help. Sorry I asked a question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a dict-comprehension:

```
In [94]: dic={'1': 2, '0': 0, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 0, '6': 0, '9': 0, '8': 0}

In [95]: {x:y for x,y in dic.items() if y!=0}
Out[95]: {'1': 2, '2': 4, '3': 4, '4': 1, '5': 1}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
```

Comment: This will remove values like `False`,`[]`,`None` as well.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yep.