# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python

What is wrong in my code, but I can get my expected result.

I am trying to remove all "#" in the list.

funds_U is the list of data:

```
In [3]: funds_U
Out[3]: 
[u'#',
 u'#',
 u'MMFU_U',
 u'#',
 u'#',
 u'AAI_U',
 u'TGI_U',
 u'JAS_U',
 u'TAG_U',
 u'#',
 u'#',
 u'AAT_U',
 u'BGR_U',
 u'BNE_U',
 u'IGE_U',
 u'#',
 u'#',
 u'DGF_U',
 u'BHC_U',
 u'FCF_U',
 u'SHK_U',
 u'VCF_U',
 u'#',
 u'JEM_U',
 u'SBR_U',
 u'TEM_U',
 u'#',
 u'#',
 u'BAB_U',
 u'BGA_U',
 u'#']
```

The following is the code:

```
In [4]: for fund_U in funds_U[:]:
   ...:     funds_U.remove(u"#")
   ...:
```

The following is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9aaa02e32e76> in <module>()
      1 for fund_U in funds_U[:]:
----> 2     funds_U.remove(u"#")
      3 

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Learn at least the basics of the language before trying to use it.

Comment: `while u'#' in FUNDS_U: FUNDS_U.remove(u'#')` is one way of doing it ... but you should really use a list comprehension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), if the item doesn't exist in the list, `remove()` will throw an error. Right now your code iterates through every item in the list and tries to remove that many `#`s. Since not every item is a `#`, `remove()` will throw an error as the list runs out of `#`s.

Try a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
funds_U = [x for x in funds_U if x != u'#']
```

This will make a new list that consists of every element in `funds_U` that is not `u'#'`.

Answer (score 6):

I would do this so:

```
new = [item for item in funds_U if item!=u'#']
```

This is a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It goes through every item in funds_U and adds it to the new list if it's not `u'#'`.

Answer (score 1):

This will modify the original object, so in case there were other variables pointing to the same object then their links will remain intact.

```
FUNDS_U[:] = [x for x in FUNDS_U if x != "#"]
```