# Efficiently choosing x *different* elements in a list at random

Tags: python, list, select, random, weighted

I have a list:

```
a = [1,2,1,1,3,5,6,2]
```

I want to select, say 3 elements at random from this list, but **they must all be different**.

I need to preserve the 'weight' of each element, so sampling from set(a) is not possible.

So far, my solution is:

```
while condition == False:
    mysample = random.sample(a, 3)
    if len(set(mysample)) - len(mysample) !=0:
        condition = False
    else:
        condition = True
```

But this forces me to re-sample as many times as it takes for the elements to all be different. This works fine for small sampling, but for large sampling, my code becomes very inefficient...

Comment: It can return duplicates if you give it a list with duplicates. The OP wants a list with no duplicates but that is still weighted such that more common elements are more likely to appear than less common ones.

Comment: @aruisdante `random.sample(a, 3)` yielded `[1, 1, 6]` on my machine. It returned two of the three `1`s in the list.

Comment: sample 1, then remove that all occurences of that in the original list. Repeat until you have the required number of elements. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list

Comment: @JohnKugelman Ah wait, they do say later that it's uniqueness based on index, not value. They don't highlight that well. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can shuffle and take the first three non repeated elements:

```
import random
random.shuffle(your_list)
three_elements = set()
for v in your_list:
  if len(three_elements) == 3: break
  three_elements.add(v)
```

Comment: Most efficient (and elegant!) for small lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = []
seen = set()
while len(l) < 3:
    ch = choice(a)
    if ch not in seen:
        l.append(ch)
        seen.add(ch)
print(l)
```

Depending on the ratio of actual different numbers to elements different approaches will have different advantages:

```
In [7]: a = [choice(range(10000)) for _ in range(100000)]

In [6]: import random

In [7]: a = [choice(range(10000)) for _ in range(100000)]

In [8]: %%timeit
random.shuffle(a)
three_elements = set()
for v in a:
    if len(three_elements) == 5000:
        break
    if not v in three_elements:
        three_elements.add(v)
   ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 36.5 ms per loop

In [9]: %%timeit                          
l = []
seen = set()
while len(l) < 5000:
    ch = choice(a)
    if ch not in seen:
        l.append(ch)
        seen.add(ch)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.16 ms per loop
```

Running your code after 10 mins I had to exit the process as it was still going so whatever you choose will be a major improvement.

Using shuffle would be more efficient if you had a greater ratio of repeats to actual items in the list and you wanted a very large sample size, otherwise the cost of shuffling will make it less efficient than simply using a set and choice,

Answer (score 0):

```
while count < sampleSize: # where sampeSize is the number of values you want
    s = random.sample(a, 1)
    filter(lambda x: x != s, a)
    mysample.append(s)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more complicated than necessary, but here is an implementation that uses a modified version of [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

```
import itertools
import random

def element_at(iterable, index, default=None):
    return next(itertools.islice(iterable, index, None), default)

def sample_unique(iterable, size):
    S = set()
    for index, item in enumerate(iterable):
        if len(S) < size:
            S.add(item)
        else:
            r = random.randint(0, index)
            if r < size:
                other = element_at(S, r)
                if item not in S:
                    S.remove(other)
                    S.add(item)
    return S
```