# Recursive function in removing occurence in list python

Tags: python, list, recursion, removeall

```
def remove_all1(x,s):
    def loop(x,s,ss):
        while s!=[]:
            if x == s[0]:
                return loop(x,s[2:],ss+[s[1]])
            else:
                return loop(x,s[1:],ss+[s[0]])
        return ss
    return loop(x,s,[])
```

This is the one I made by recursive tail function to remove recursive value x and if :

```
print(remove_all1(3,[4,3,5,6,3,2,1]))
```

I would get:

```
[4,5,6,2,1]
```

The exact result I want. But for the recursive function here:

```
def remove_all0(x,s):
    while s!=[]:
        if x == s[0]:
            ss = [s[1]] + remove_all0(x,s[2:])
            return ss 
        else:
            s1 = [s[0]] + [remove_all0(x, s[1:])]
            return s1 
    if s==[]:
        return s
print(remove_all0(3,[4,3,5,6,3,2,1]))
```

I would not get the same result. Instead, I got:

```
[4, [5, 6, [2, 1, []]]]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `remove_all0` returns a list, which you're wrapping in another list when you call it recursively

Comment: I think this post might also be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list it shows how to efficiently remove all occurrences of an item from a list in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `else` clause when you wrap the returned value from `remove_all0` which is a  list, and make it a list containing that list.  Just remove those square brackets and you'll get the results you want:

```
def remove_all0(x,s):
    while s!=[]:
        if x == s[0]:
            ss = [s[1]] + remove_all0(x,s[2:])
            return ss
        else:
            s1 = [s[0]] + remove_all0(x, s[1:])
            return s1
    if s==[]:
        return s
print(remove_all0(3,[4,3,5,6,3,2,1]))
```

gives

```
[4, 5, 6, 2, 1]
```