# remove specific values from the python list

Tags: python-2.7

Here is the list
['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', '00', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', '00', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', '00', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', '00', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '', '00', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', '00', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', '', '00', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', '00', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', '', '00', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', '00', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', '00', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

I would like to remove '' and '00' from the list

result should be like this

['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3',   'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5',   'TOWER INQ', 'T',   'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2',   'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C',   'MONETARY IM80', 'W',   'MONETARY-IM201', 'D',   'OCF INQ', 'G',   'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K',   'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4',   'MEMO POST', 'Z',   'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

I tried this 
apa= [aa for aa in apa if aa != "''" or aa != "00"]

getting same result

Comment: Don't you mean `and`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
for i in list:
    if i = "00":
        del list[i]
```

You can also use:

```
list.remove('00');
```

Answer (score 0):

res=['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', '00', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', '00', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', '00', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', '00', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '', '00', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', '00', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', '', '00', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', '00', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', '', '00', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', '00', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', '00', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

res=[x for x in res if x not in ('00','')]

print res

['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', 'OCF INQ', 'G', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', '00',
     'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', '00', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', '00', 
     'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', '00', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '',
     '00', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', '00', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', 
     '', '00', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', '00', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO',
     'RATE INQ', 'K', '', '00', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', '00', 
     'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', '00', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

print [x for x in lst if x != '00' and x != '']

#Output
['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', 
 '5', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', 'COMB STMT MAINT',
 'C', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', 'OCF INQ', 'G',
 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', 
 'MEMO POST', 'Z', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop

```
list1 =  ['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', '00', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', '00', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', '00', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', '00', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '', '00', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', '00', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', '', '00', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', '00', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', '', '00', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', '00', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', '00', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']

while '00' in list1: list1.remove('00')
print(list1)
```

The output will be

```
['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', '', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', '', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0']
```

With all the '00' terms removed

Answer (score 0):

Single liner:

```
filter(lambda a: a!='' and a!='00', ['DEFAULT SECURITY', 'YES', 'ACCT INQ', '3', '', '00', 'STOP/HOLD ADD', '5', '', '00', 'TOWER INQ', 'T', '', '00', 'ACCT FIELD MNT', '2', '', '00', 'COMB STMT MAINT', 'C', '', '00', 'MONETARY IM80', 'W', '', '00', 'MONETARY-IM201', 'D', '', '00', 'OCF INQ', 'G', '', '00', 'ACCESS ALL FUNC', 'NO', 'RATE INQ', 'K', '', '00', 'NAME/ADDR CHG', '4', '', '00', 'MEMO POST', 'Z', '', '00', 'FLOOR LIMITS', '0'])
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157160/761963