# Python List and remove a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to programming. I was trying to understand different data structure in python. In List i was trying:

```
mylist = [1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
print mylist
mylist.remove(2)
print mylist
```

It is supposed to remove 2 from the list. It does but the first one only.
The output is like:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

How can i remove all the match ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. List Comprehension seems the right one for me. But i am confused which one i should select as answer. Thanks guys for answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: But it is almost much more clearer question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html), this behavior is expected:

> `list.remove(x)`
>
> **Remove the first item from the list whose value is x**. It is an error if there is no such item.

To remove all occurences of value from list you may use list comprehension:

```
seq = [1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
seq = [value for value in seq in value != 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use 
[filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
>>> filter(lambda x:x!=2, mylist)
[1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3]
```

Or simple list comprehension.

```
my_list = [i for i in my_list if i!=2]
```

You can even use `remove()` to get the correct result by doing this:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         mylist.remove(2)
...     except:
...         break
... 
>>> mylist
[1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3]
```

But, this is ugly, and often causes unexpected behavior. You should never modify a list while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x != 2]
```

This is simpler than a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension is probably the most pythonic way of doing this:

```
mylist = [number for number in mylist if number != 2]
```

This is because `list.remove(x)` only removes the first occurrence of `x` in the list. The above solution will create a new list based on `mylist` that will contain all elements of `mylist` if they are unequal to 2.

Answer (score 1):

From python help:

```
help(list.remove)
```

you can get this explanation:

> L.remove(value) -- remove first occurrence of value.
>       Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

You can achieve it by using list comprehension:

```
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x != 2]
```

It just create a new list according to your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

another way(if you wont create new list):

```
while 2 in mylist:
    mylist.remove(2)
```