# How do you count how many of a certain number is in a list, and then remove those? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a project for my Intro to Programming class, and I need to count how many 9's are in a given list. I would like to save the number of how many there are to a variable, however when I try to save a variable with list.count(9)" I get an error. Is there a way to save it, or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

```
# create a list with random values
>>> import random
>>> my_list = list(random.randint(1,9) for x in range(10))
>>> my_list
[4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 7]

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(my_list)
>>> c
Counter({2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1, 8: 4})
>>> c[8]
4

# drop all 8's from my_list
>>> my_list = [x for x in my_list if x != 8]
>>> my_list
[4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: I did not know about Counter, thanks for showing this.  Did the OP change the question?  This is the second answer I have seen telling how to remove all instances of a value from the list.

Comment: @tnknepp Good point.  Dropping the 9s from the list is in the question title, but not in the question text.
P.S.: Yay plug for [`Counter`](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html), it's useful all over the place.

Comment: Ahh, right on.  I thought I remembered seeing the need to drop values somewhere, but never checked the title.  Sorry...now really glad I did not downvote.  Upvoting now!

Answer (score 1):

yourList.count(9) will give you the number of 9's.
for removal, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: The OP already has list.count(9), but claims to have some error when saving to a variable.  No downvote here, but this answer does not address the OP's question (not that you could due to the lack of detail in the original question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
my_list = [1,5,6,9,4,9,9,2,3,9]
count_9 = sum(1 for i in my_list if i==9)
# to remove the 9s
filtered_list = [i for i in my_list if i!=9]
```

Comment: .remove() removes the first occurence only