# Remove all occurrences of an integer from list

Tags: python, list

In python, how can I remove all occurrences of an integer from a list. For example:

```
list_a = [5, 20, 15, 10, 55, 30, 65]
list_a.METHOD(5)
print(list_a)
[20, 10, 30]
```

Essentially, the method removes anything that contains a 5. Not specifically multiples of 5, given that 10 and 20 do not contain a 5. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of a value from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Oh, it's not a dupe of that, per se.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_a = [5, 20, 15, 10, 55, 30, 65]
list_a = [x for x in list_a if "5" not in str(x)]
print(list_a)
[20, 10, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
[x for x in list_a if str(x).find('5') < 0]
```

That's a list comprehension that converts each number to a string and then searches the string for the character `5`. `find` returns `-1` if not found so we keep only things where the `5` wasn't found.

Comment: if you want to test only if a substring is in a string, use `in`, and not `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and lambda.

```
filter(lambda x:"5" not in str(x) , [5, 20, 15, 10, 55, 30, 65])
```