# How to delete all occurrences of a value from a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, removeall

Let `h` be my matrix

```
h=[[0,346,34,6,7,0,0,34634,6,0],[2352,205230,523,50,5023,502,350,0,0]]
```

and I want to delete all the zeros from `h`.

So the result should be:

```
h=[[346,34,6,7,34634,6],[2352,205230,523,50,5023,502,350]]
```

I tried several different things from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list) and other questions but nothing seems to work for a matrix. Is there any nice solution to that?

Comment: is this a numpy matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the matrix **in-place**, you could do it with a function like the following. The trick is to go through the elements of each row backwards so that the indices of successive elements aren't changed because of ones being removed earlier.

```
def remove_zeros(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        length = len(row)-1
        for i, elem in enumerate(reversed(row)):
            if not elem:  # zero value?
                row.pop(length-i)

h = [[0, 346, 34, 6, 7, 0, 0, 34634, 6, 0], [2352, 205230, 523, 50, 5023, 502, 350, 0, 0]]

remove_zeros(h)

print(h)  # -> [[346, 34, 6, 7, 34634, 6], [2352, 205230, 523, 50, 5023, 502, 350]]
```

Comment: I would use `reversed(row)` instead of `row[::-1]`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista: Sure, that would work, too, and is more readable. However most "Pythonistas" would immediately recognize the `[::=1]` since it was what was commonly used before the `reversed()` built-in was added to the language.

Comment: yes, but as of right now, it is more readable and more efficient as it does not copy the row, it just iterate over it

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista: Ok, ok... `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use list comprehension:

```
h = [[element for element in row if element] for row in h]
```

So here we iterate over every `row` in `h`. For each row we construct a new list `[element for element in row if element]`. This means that for every `element` in that `row`, we check if it is equal to `0` (with `if element`). If it is not, `bool(element)` is `True` and thus we add `element` to that list. Otherwise we omit `element`.

Comment: `chain.from_iterable(h.tolist())` in place of `h` if it's a `numpy` matrix.

Comment: @NickilMaveli: why do you need to `chain`?

Comment: It's because `tolist()` creates an additional outer `list` which you'd need to flatten.

Comment: @NickilMaveli: I've tested it and you get a 2d list back which is what we want.