# Remove square brackets from a list of characters

Tags: python, string, list, strip

I seem to have a very silly problem,

```
>>> a = ['[','1','2',']','[','2','3',']']
>>> b = str(a)
>>> print b
['[', '1', '2', ']', '[', '2', '3', ']']
>>> b.strip('[')
"'[', '1', '2', ']', '[', '2', '3', ']']"
>>> b.strip('[').strip(']')
"'[', '1', '2', ']', '[', '2', '3', ']'"
>>>
```

I can't remove the square brackets from my list, I thought maybe converting it to a string, and `strip` the `[` `]` characters would help, but doesn't seem to be the solution.

output_test_post.txt contains this:

```
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0 [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 3 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ] [ 4 1 ]
```

Current processing:

```
map_test = {}
os.chdir(output_test)
with open("output_test_post.txt",'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        map_test[name] = str(row[1:])
        print map_test[name]
        raw_input("Somethign")
map_train = {}
```

Comment: I think you should fix the *source* of this silliness.

Comment: `replace()` is your friend.

Comment: how did you end up `a`? casting a list to string then back to a list is rarely helpful...

Comment: use `replace`. replace all the brackets with empty strings.

Comment: Do you want to remove all occurences of an item in a list? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1157106/5754656

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of a value from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-python-list)

Comment: "I'm wearing pants on my head. How do I take them off?" *Don't put your pants on your head*, and *don't do whatever got you this `a` list*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ha...  that would indeed help... Why I didn't i think of that.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I am currently extracting statics  [µ,sigma]  They are stored in a csv file, so `csvreader` puts them into a list... 

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        map_test[name] = str(row[1:])

Comment: yeah so `str(row[1:])` would be converting the list `row[1:]` to a string, which gives you `[]` characters then I'm guessing you are using `.split(", ")` to get it back into a list?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `str(a)` is something I recently added, as an atempt of trying to remove the extra character.

Comment: the newly posted code still doesn't show how/when you got `['[','1','2',']','[','2','3',']']` as a value, where did it come from? Does the csv have square bracket characters in it?

Comment: its how the file is stored @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: oh huh, thats odd.  sometimes people convert between list and string and then ask how they can clean up the result. (hence [comments like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528081/remove-square-bracket-character-from-a-list-of-character?noredirect=1#comment76048000_44528081)) so I'm glad this wasn't one of those cases :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[x for x in a if x not in "[]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the brackets out.

```
>>> a = ['[','1','2',']','[','2','3',']']
>>> b = [i for i in a if i not in ['[', ']']]
>>> b
['1', '2', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp for it

```
re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b=list(filter(lambda a: a!='[' and a!=']' and a!=',' and a!=' ' and a!="'", b))
```

note: b is your input string