# Delete None in python list

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Q1.
[image]

I want to get output as:

```
[Randy, Shaw]
```

Output Looks like

```
['Randy', 'None', 'None', 'Shaw', 'None', 'None']
```

But it is not removing 'None' values.
Here is my code..

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('C:/Users/Desktop/test.xlsx')
print(workbook.get_sheet_names())

sheet=workbook.get_sheet_by_name('marks')

iterheaders = iter(sheet[1])
headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in iterheaders if cell is not None and cell != '']

Keyword_list = list(filter(None, headers))
```

I even tried the following but it didn't work either:

```
Keyword_list = [i for i in headers if (None) != len(i)]
```

Q2. In the same code what if I  want to get the sheet by its index rather than by its name in openpyxl. How do I do that?

Comment: Because that is the *string* `"None"` not the singleton, NoneType object `None`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter like so:

```
s = ['Randy', 'None', 'None', 'Shaw', 'None', 'None']

s = [i for i in s if i != "None"]
```

Keep in mind that in your list you have the string `"None"`, not the object `None`

For Q2:

```
workbook = load_workbook('C:/Users/Desktop/test.xlsx')

sheet = wworkbook.worksheets[0] #here, either loop over or access by whatever index you want.
```

Comment: Hi, that worked.Thanks! But what about Q2? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Your none values are not literal `None` type values. Their strings. Therefore, you need to test them against strings. eg:

```
>>> lst = ['Randy', 'None', 'None', 'Shaw', 'None', 'None']
>>> [el for el in lst if el != 'None']
['Randy', 'Shaw']
>>>
```