# how to remove an item completely from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list,

```
numbers=["one","two","three","one","one"]
```

when I am doing,

```
numbers.remove("one")
```

it returns

```
["two","three","one","one"]
```

but I want to remove it completely,

My expected output is,

```
output=["two","three"]
```

Comment: There is similar question discussion about this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list

Comment: yes, that's a classic duplicate, thanks.

Comment: ok, Do I need to remove the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "one"]
[element for element in numbers if element != "one"]
=> ["two", "three"]
```

We used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for doing the job, check the link for details. But basically - we created a new list, filtering out the undesired element via a condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

How about a `list comprehension`

```
[i for i in numbers if i!="one"]
```

You can also use a `filter` (**Python 2.x**)

```
filter(lambda x: x!="one",numbers)
```

Output:

```
['two', 'three']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer