# How to remove more than one elements from list in python at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say i have `a=[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]`

I want to remove all the zero's at the same time. can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "at the same time" ?

Comment: Solution to this question is [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solution to do that. As list comprehension is already explained I am trying something different. Using lambda function

Python 2.x

```
>>> x = [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
>>> filter(lambda a: a != 0, x)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Python 3.x or above

```
>>> x = [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
>>> list(filter((0).__ne__, x))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

or

```
>>> x = [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
>>> list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, x))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for that:

```
a=[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
print([value for value in a if value != 0])
```

This will remove all elements from list with value equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
b = [x for x in a if x!= 0]

>>> b
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.