# Remove all matching value from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have following list of lists object

```
myList = [[123,0.0,345,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [45,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [67,8,0.0,5,6,7,0.0]
```

And I want to remove all zeroes from this list.

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list) and coded like following.

```
myList = list(filter(lambda j:j!=0,myList[i]) for i in range(len(myList)))
```

But I am getting the list of filter object as the output. What is the error in the code.

```
[<filter object at 0x7fe7bdfff8d0>, <filter object at 0x7fe7a6eaaf98>, <filter object at 0x7fe7a6f08048>,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to cast the inner `filter` function with a `list`, when you do that, the code works as expected :)

```
myList = [[123,0.0,345,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [45,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [67,8,0.0,5,6,7,0.0]]

#Cast inner filter into a list
myList = list(list(filter(lambda j:j!=0,myList[i])) for i in range(len(myList)))
print(myList)
```

The output will be

```
[[123, 345], [45], [67, 8, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Also a simpler way of understanding will be to use a list-comprehension

```
myList = [[123,0.0,345,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [45,0.0,0.0,0.0],
 [67,8,0.0,5,6,7,0.0]]

#Using list comprehension, in the inner loop check if item is non-zero
myList = [ [item for item in li if item != 0] for li in myList ]
print(myList)
```

The output will be

```
[[123, 345], [45], [67, 8, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: When does the second filter happen in this function - taking a look at this and am curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
newList = [list(filter(lambda j:j!=0, i)) for i in myList]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[[123, 345], [45], [67, 8, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```
cleaned = [ [e for e in row if e != 0] for row in myList ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to wrap filter, not the whole statement:

```
myList = [list(filter(lambda j:j!=0,myList[i]) for i in range(len(myList))]
```

Also, you can skip the index, and iterate by lists in `myList`:

```
myList = [list(filter(lambda j:j!=0, inner_list) for inner_list in myList]
```