# Why does the filter function not work in this case?

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

I've written this code for removing characters from a string. I used the filter function but it returns the same list without modification.

```
a = "Hello !!!!,  . / "
a1 = list(a)


def it(at):
    k = at.copy()
    charlist = [",", ".", "/", " ", ":", ";", "\'", "\"", "!"]
    for x in charlist:
        filter(lambda t: t != x, k)
    print(k)


it(a1)
```

[I've referred to this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1157106/10892048)

Comment: filter doesn't modify the container you are filtering in-place. It returns an iterator over the filtered elements in that container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` returns the filtered iterable; it doesn't modify it in place.

```
>>> def it(at):
...     charlist = [",", ".", "/", " ", ":", ";", "\'", "\"", "!"]
...     print(list(filter(lambda t: t not in charlist, at)))
...
>>> it(a1)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

An implementation closer to your original code would be to filter in a loop the way you were doing, but to reassign `k` each time:

```
>>> def it(at):
...     k = at.copy()
...     charlist = [",", ".", "/", " ", ":", ";", "\'", "\"", "!"]
...     for x in charlist:
...         k = list(filter(lambda t: t != x, k))
...     print(k)
...
>>> it(a1)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: How can I perform the same operation using slicing instead of a for loop? Something like :    z = list(filter(lambda t: t != charlist[::], k))

Comment: Look at the first part of my answer for how to do this without a for loop (it doesn't involve slicing).

Answer (score 0):

Filter method returns an iterator that is already filtered.
Refer to below code

```
a = "Hello !!!!,  . / "
a1 = list(a)


def it(at):
    k = at.copy()
    charlist = [",", ".", "/", " ", ":", ";", "\'", "\"", "!"]
    new_k = None
    for x in charlist:
        new_k = filter(lambda t: t != x, k)
    for s in new_k:
        print(s)


it(a1)
```

Comment: How can I perform the same operation using slicing instead of a for loop? Something like : z = list(filter(lambda t: t != charlist[::], k))