# List Comprehension (Python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

> Q. Write a function
>
> ```
> remove(data, value)
> ```
>
> that returns a new list that contains the same elements as the list data except for those that equal value. Use a list comprehension. Your function should remove all items equal to value. For example, remove([3, 1, 5, 3, 9], 3) should return the list [1, 5, 9].

Down below is what I worked on, but it returns None.

```
def remove (data,value):
    ans = [ data.remove(value) for ele in data if value == ele ]
    return ans

assert(remove([3,1,5,3,9], 1) ==[3,5,3,9])
```

These should work for this function. Please let me know what should I do ??

Comment: Why do you think it returns `[None]`? What does `data.remove()` return? What's the point of modifying `data` if you're returning `ans`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to have a descriptive title. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. It would help if you provided the actual output in the question itself. See [mre] for reference.

Comment: Hint, `data.remove` *modifies `data` and returns `None`*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157132/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove elements in a list while you're iterating over it.
create a new list and keep all elements except the ones that match ele.

```
def remove(data, value):
    ans = [ele for ele in data if value != ele]
    return ans
```

Comment: *"you cannot remove elements in a list while you're iterating over it"* - You can actually, but it might cause unexpected results.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [answer] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list) however, I don't think your case of the issue is well-explained.

There are a few clear issues which are seen in the comments, but not clearly Answering the Question.

- [`.remove()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of lists will remove the first instance of its argument and then return `None`
- you *both* change the original list *and* create a new list, while you would be better served by only doing one as-detailed by numerous answers in the duplicate question!

Answer (score -1):

```
def remove(data, value):
   return [i for i in data if i != value]
```

This will iterate over everything properly.