# How to delete all specific element ​from Python list?

Tags: python

I have a list like this.
`a = ['\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n']`
As far as I know, the remove, pop, delete method only removes one by one.
If I want to remove all'\n' from this list, the only way to do this is to use remove via a for or a while loop using remove method? Or is there a specific method?

Comment: list comprehension `a = [x for x in a if x != '\n']` is your friend

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not really. There may be other references to the list.

Comment: okay then: `a[:] = [x for x in a if x != '\n']` (but OP didn't specify that part)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
a = ['\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n']
list(filter(('\n').__ne__, a))
```

Comment: it's an obvious duplicate but I like `('\n').__ne__`

Comment: but it's covered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157160/6451573. I would be cool if people voted to close instead of FFGITW answering. And list comprehensions are generally used, not this clunky list+filter+__ne__ stuff