# How to split a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

Is there a way to split a list of strings per character?

Here is a simple list that I want split per `"!"`:

```
name1 = ['hello! i like apples!', ' my name is ! alfred!']
first = name1.split("!")
print(first)
```

I know it's not expected to run,  I essentially want a new list of strings whose strings are now separated by `"!"`. So output can be:

```
["hello", "i like apples", "my name is", "alfred"]
```

Comment: Why is `name1` a list in the first place?  I'm guessing you want either `name1[0].split('!')` or `[name.split('!') for name in name1]`.

Comment: @0x5453 - Because its a list of strings?

Comment: What about the case where a string does not end in a "!"? Should two strings concatenate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your given output, I've "solved" the problem.
So basically what I do is:

1.) Create one big string by simply concatenating all of the strings contained in your list.

2.) Split the big string by character "!"

Code:

```
lst = ['hello! i like apples!', 'my name is ! alfred!']
s = "".join(lst)

result = s.split('!')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['hello', ' i like apples', 'my name is ', ' alfred', '']
```

Comment: It would be a bit more efficient to do `s = "".join(lst)`.

Comment: @tdelaney definitely, thanks for the comment. I shall add this to the code, as the for-loop does look not look like a pythonic solution.

Comment: This is not what the op stated as expected output: There is a `''` entry at the end of the list (it's clear why it is there, but it shouldn't)?

Comment: @Timus - agreed. There should be a strip and a test for empty in there.

Comment: I assumed the OP made a typo when putting empty spaces around the exclamation marks. The empty strings can be removed in case the OP does not need them (and I suppose he/she doesn't) by simply removing elements from a list.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list

Comment: Sure you can. But if you address both issues (the unwanted whitespace with `strip` and the extra `''` entries with `remove` or otherwise) your solution looks quite different.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop on each string and flatten its `split` result to a new list:

```py
name1=['hello! i like apples!',' my name is ! alfred!']
print([s.strip() for sub in name1 for s in sub.split('!') if s])
```

Gives:

```
['hello', 'i like apples', 'my name is', 'alfred']
```

Comment: You could add a strip to that `[ss for ss in (s.strip() for sub in name1 for s in sub.split('!')) if ss]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name1 = ['hello! i like apples!', 'my name is ! alfred!']           
new_list = []                                                       
for l in range(0, len(name1)):                                      
    new_list += name1[l].split('!')
    new_list.remove('')                        
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

['hello', ' i like apples', 'my name is ', ' alfred']

Comment: sorry, please see updated version, i forgot to split the original list