# I want to remove a specific element and its duplicates from a list in python 3.8

Tags: python, list

```
l1=[int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
itemToRemove=int(input())
for i in l1:
    if i == itemToRemove:
        l1.remove(i)
print(l1)
```

```
input: 1 2 2 2 3 4
       2

output:1 2 3 4
```

but the expected output should be

```
output:1 3 4
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this link for the some approches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the list while iterating over it. This is never a good idea. A better idea would be to use a while loop that ran whenever the element is in the list. Then, you could remove the element.

Code:

```
l1=[int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
itemToRemove=int(input())

while itemToRemove in l1:
    l1.remove(itemToRemove)

print(l1)
```

If you want to do it with a for loop, iterate over a copy of a list:

```
l1=[int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
itemToRemove=int(input())
for i in l1.copy():
    if i == itemToRemove:
        l1.remove(i)
print(l1)
```

You can also iterate over the number of times the `itemToRemove` is in `l1`.

```
l1=[int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
itemToRemove=int(input())
for _ in range(l1.count(itemToRemove)):
    l1.remove(itemToRemove)
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use while loop to compare:

```
l1=[int(i) for i in input()]
itemToRemove=int(input())
while itemToRemove in l1: l1.remove(itemToRemove)
print (l1)
```