# How to Remove element from the list

Tags: python, list

### I want to remove all rohitsharma names from the list remove function is remove only the first one what should I do?

```
names=['rohitsharma','msd','Brettlee','Dravid','rohitsharma','akhil','python','rohitsharma','dhoni','rohitsharma','rohitsharma']
print(names)
names.remove('rohitsharma')
print(names)
```

Comment: Could be googled it veeeery quickly and easily.. Anyway, [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-list-clear-pop-remove-del/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list)

Comment: `names = [item for item in names if names !='rohitsharma']`

Answer (score 1):

Build from scratch to remove all occurrences:

```
names[:] = [x for x in names if x != "rohitsharma"]
```

This is linear (done in a single iteration) while repeated removal is bound by both the length of the list and the number of occurrences.
You could also get functional about this one and use `filter` with the ready-made dunder method:

```
names[:] = filter("rohitsharma".__ne__, names)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method to check if each element satisfies the condition or not.

```
names = list(filter(lambda x: x !='rohitsharma', names))
print(names)
```

**Output**

```
['msd', 'Brettlee', 'Dravid', 'akhil', 'python', 'dhoni']
```