# Remove all values "Home " from scraped list of names

Tags: python, list, remove-if

I have a list of names I have scraped from a website. In that list, there are some observations that are not names but are called `"Home    "`. I can remove them by `uni_name.pop()`, but this is not easily repeatable.

How do I remove all values from the list that is `"Home    "` at once?

Thank you in advance!

I tried writing this:

```
uni_name(filter(Home    ).__ne__, uni_name)
```

But it gave me an `NameError: name 'Home' is not defined`

Comment: `Home` is a variable that (as the error correctly states) is not defined. `"Home"` would be a string that you need (probably with some trailing spaces).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych But even then, OP's use of `filter()` would be nonsensical.

Comment: can you provide an example of what the data looks like, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @AKX that is true. I'm just explaining the error. The approach in your answer is a much better way to do it anyway (though I'd argue that this question should be closed as duplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all occurrences of a value from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all `"Home"`s (ignoring [any number of leading/trailing spaces](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)), the Pythonic way is to [use a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> uni_name = ["hello", "Home          ", "   Home", "World"]
>>> uni_name = [name for name in uni_name if name.strip() != "Home"]
>>> print(uni_name)
['hello', 'World']
```

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you! Will save me a lot of time from manually uni_name.pop()'ing